# Changing a variable changes also another variable. Prevent variables having the same reference

Tags: c#, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I have a class that the constructor requires a class and other things like:

```
public class SomeClass<T>
{
    //global private variables for class
    List<T> originalList = new List<T>;
    List<T> tempList = new List<T>;

    public SomClass(List<T> listParam, string name, ..etc)
    {
        originalList = listParam;
        tempList = listParam;

        originalList.removeAt(0);  // this also removes an item from tempList.


    }
}
```

I know this is because originalList and tempList have the same reference. How could I make them have diferent references. I use the tempList to filter results and whenever I want to refresh I use the originalList

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make a copy of `listParam`, rather than just assigning its reference:

```
tempList = listParam.ToList();
```

Note that this does *not* create a copy of each object in the list, but just a copy of the references to those objects.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of accepting a `List<T>`, accept an `IEnumerable<T>`. If you then want a concrete list, call `.ToList()` on it.

The original source is unaffected, and you have a copy. You also have the benefit of being able to take anything that supports the interface.

**Edit:** I misread the code in the question, your copy is in the same class. Well, it's in two places, the class *and* the caller. I stand by my suggestion, but yes, you'd need two invocations of `.ToList()`, one for each copy.

Comment: "Instead of accepting a List<T>, accept an IEnumerable<T>" --- any reason to do that when he specifically need a list?

Comment: @zerkms, for the benefit of supporting more in the class. It supports any sequence of type T, it does not need to be a specific implementation. If all he ever *wants* to support is the specific implementation, he has that option. But using the least-restrictive interface simply gives him more options, that's all.

Comment: Yes, gives more options and requires to copy the list each time (even when we don't need a copy and list is significantly big) ;-)

Comment: @zerkms, he'll have to copy the list anyway as per his requirement. But, yes, to support *two* independent lists in his class, he'd copy it twice using this approach. However, if he wants the list at the *source* to remain independent, *he'd still need to do this.*